# Send img data stored in MongoDB from Node to React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I stored img data in MongoDB

```
app.post("/api/setImage", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    const avatar = {
      img: {
        data: await fsp.readFile(
          path.join(__dirname, "/uploads/", req.file.filename)
        ),
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      },
    };
    await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
      img: {
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        data: await fsp.readFile(req.file.path),
      },
    });
    const user = await userModel.findById(userId);
    res.set("Content-Type", user.img.contentType);
    res.send(user.img.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

img from  mongo

[image]

console.log in Node shows data from db like below

```
testData <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 09 06 07 13 13 12 15 13 13 13 16 15 15 17 17 17 16 18 15 16 17 17 15 18 
17 ... 6945 more bytes, _subtype: 0, _m ...
```

On the client  I got a data like this

```
response {data: '����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00��\x00�\x00\t\x06\x07\x13\x13\x12\x15\x13\x13\x13\x16\x15\x15\x17\x17\x17\x16\x18\x15\x16\x17\x17\x15\x18\x17…�AC������?�\x1B�\x7F1X�*D�\x19�z�"\x16O���V,@1��F~\x13�Bj���\x14?��', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

How can I show this data as image? What do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to send buffer data is

```
const user = await userModel.findById(userId)
res.set('Content-Type', user.image.contentType)
res.send(user.image.data)
```

[reference](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send)

---

There is also quite a lot mistakes in your code, after fixing it should look like this

```
const fsp = require('fs/promises')

// const fsPromises =  require('fs/promises')
app.post('/api/setImage', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const avatar = {
      img: {
        data: await fsp.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/', req.file.filename)), // no need to concatenate 
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      },
    }
    const userId = req.body.userId
    // TODO: validate userId
    await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
      img: {
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
        data: await fsp.readFile(req.file.path), // not sure why are you reading this instead of `avatar.img.data`
      },
    })

    /// get stored img data from db
    const user = await userModel.findById(userId)
    res.set('Content-Type', user.image.contentType)
    res.send(user.image.data)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err) // @see http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler
  }
})
```

viewing image on client side, Ill assume you are using axios.

```
const resp = await axios.post(url, data, { responseType: 'blob' })
console.log(resp.data instanceof Blob) // true

const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(resp.data);
console.log(objectURL) 
// TODO: create img element and set value `src` attribute to `objectURL`
// once done clear it by calling URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)
```

IF you are using fetch see this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

Comment: I got it on the client data
: 
"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\

Comment: It's ok? Can u recommend something?

Comment: @Radomir its image in UTF-8 encoding, if you want to see that image use snippet that i have provided at end.

Comment: Big thanks, all work!